# hal command: hal deploy apply how can i use it offline?

Tags: spinnaker

I used halyard version 0.42.0-20180302093153 and Spinnaker version 1.6.0.

Is there any way that makes me to use hal command: `hal deploy apply` offline ?

Answer (score 0):

Although there was no ability to do this when you asked your question, there's been work on this since then, under https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/2640. Presumably at some point this will get officially released and the documentation will be updated accordingly, but as of today it appears to be in a "coming, but not here yet" state.